# Linux desktop as USB Display

Tags: linux, usb

I have been thinking about the feasibility of a project that I'd like to develop and I don't know if it is possible. What I want to take a standard linux computer and have it act like a USB monitor when another machine plugs into it via USB; ie. if I plug my laptop into it with a standard USB cable, my laptop OS will detect it as an external monitor and I can then mirror my screen to it. Step two would then be to capture the output from the USB and redirect it out of the linux machines VGA/DVI/HDMI display ports as if it is it's own display. The first step seems harder than the second, but I'm pretty new to Linux driver development.

My questions are:

1) Do you think this is even possible?

2) Do you know of any projects that do something similar?

Comment: [Thunderbolt 4](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+thunderbolt+4&client=ubuntu&hs=OBD&channel=fs&ei=V_6-YLTsC8vOtQbdqoRI&oq=what+is+thunderbolt+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BQgAELEDOgcIABCxAxANOgQIABANOgYIABAHEB5Q0vsCWK7HA2Dh4ANoAXACeACAAZ4BiAHpCZIBBDAuMTCYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) allows (will allow?) data transfer at 32 GB / second a second, so I would assume that the limitation you faced in 2012 is behind you at least.

Comment: Info is from the accordion-style question in link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, for a very simple reason: You can't plug two USB hosts (e.g, computers) directly into one another. While there are unfortunately some USB cables available with two A ends, trying to use one to connect two computers will at best have no effect, and may in fact cause damage to one or both hosts.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant in 2021?

Comment: I dont see why not... android does it. ADB will let you control of the device completely via usb. Kde connect will let you control another pc via wifi.

Comment: You can not install x86 Android on a PC and have this work, so Android does not do it. Android *devices* are designed as USB clients (that support being hosts via USB OTG), but an arbitrary PC does not support being a USB device.

Comment: That is false. Since there are many USB hubs that can be configured to act as either a host or a client. Linux has kernel settings for this. Saying that you need such a hub/chip, and then explaining how to configure things, would have been an actual solution.

Comment: I'm not sure there was ever a time when this answer wouldn't have been wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in 2021, due to advancements in USB, namely the versatility of the USB-C cables and the USB 3.x standards, the implementation of which is realized via these cables, [you can](https://www.cablematters.com/blog/USB-C/what-devices-use-usb-c) now use USB for remote PC display.

From cablematters.com:

> Many thin laptops also use USB-C ports for connecting to external displays in addition to charging and data because it is slimmer than older video interfaces such as VGA and HDMI.

The main reason that this is possible now, and it was not via the USB 2.0 is because of the USB-C cables themselves. The old USB 2.0 cables (called USB-A and for android phones, etc., microUSB) only had four inner wires. Furthermore, the standard itself designated 2 of them for the 5 volt power transfer. This left us with only D+ and D- signals for data transfer. Not to mention that the data transfer rate was only a [small portion of](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2020-what-are-the-maximum-power-output-and-data-transfer-rates-for-the-usb-standards) what it is now.

> The five overall main speeds of the USB standards are as follows:

```
USB 1.0: 1.5 Mbps
USB 1.1: 12 Mbps
USB 2.0: 480 Mbps
USB 3.0 and USB 3.1: 5 Gbps
USB 3.2 gen 2: 10 Gbps
```

Fast forward to USB 3.x environment. While the USB-C cable still has the four original signals mentioned above, it also provides an additional 5 signals! As one can imagine all of the possibilities due to this change alone.

As a side note, if you are interested in USB 3, both sourced articles are worth reading completely. The first especially: it really is an excellent read. I got so caught up in them that I almost forgot that I was researching a Question. :)

**EDIT:**
Adding just for clarity and completeness -- In the question above, there is a 2nd part, but that is sort of baked into  this solution, since, in the devices mentioned, the USB peripheral *is* the default display port. In other words, on these new devices, the USB actually replaces the devices that OP was wanting the USB to emulate.

Comment: @Hamid K according to the article, Not only is USB being used for this, but now, on many devices USB is the DEDICATED peripheral  for video! So anything that you use HDMI for (at least in the PC realm) can technically be done with USB... Including remote PC display. And at 10Gb/sec I would hope so. That is 5 times the ISP cap on my family's home internet at the moment!

Comment: Sorry my bounty was expired :( Anyway I was aware of USB-C monitors, but the question is about can we make a computer act like a USB monitor? That is, we attach two computers via USB cable, configure first of them, and second one see it as a regular USB display. Is it possible? Maybe that question is not exactly this and I should ask it as a separate question?

Comment: I wish the bounty would start when user starts answering the question. I started answer 2 or 3 hrs before expiry. However, I continued sourcing / subject research alongside answer. I also spent way too much time digging into USB 3 standards, as Ive been meaning to read up on it for the last year or so. Oh well, I learned a lot and enjoyed doing the extra research. That is worth more to me than a few rep. Anyway, If it did count from edit start, I am sure people would abuse.

Comment: @hamid k Are you referring to dual-monitor setup? For example, having 2 laptops sitting side by side, running a single OS instance.. If so, it is definately feasible at the very least. USB 3, as you know, provides more than enough resources for comm. I would check github, as there would need to be some sort of framework to handle divying of hardware resources (memory, cpu, etc.) That said it probably exists somewhere on gh, EDIT: Even if one pc does the work, as you suggested, you would need some type of library or framework to handle configuration. Still I am gonna try on Ubuntu.

Comment: Dual monitor is one pc with two monitor, my scenario is two computer with separate cpu and os, we configure one of them to act like a usb monitor and show input on some window for example, then attach them with a usb and see the second screen in the first one out of the box.

Comment: This isn’t a solution though. It’s basically just a comment about you reading an article you liked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To connect two machines together with USB you will need a special USB cable.  This isn't as simple as a back-back one because of the way USB identifies devices.

Normally [back-back USB](http://www.networkusb.com/index.html) cables actually have a network chip in them to make it efectively USB-ethernet-ethernet-USB link.

Once you have a network link you can just use something like VNC to mirror the screen

Comment: VNC is very far away from being equivalent to a full display. E.g. for anything other than X. From boot to console to games to other operating systems that don't support VNC.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux to not be the host, the USB chip has to support **gadget mode**. Which means it as the “gadget” instead of the host. Linux supports gadget mode just fine. You can enable the drivers in the kernel (compilation) settings. E.g. this is the normal way Linux works on smartphones and the like. But your desktop PC probably has little reason to have a chipset that supports this.

But all that does not really matter, because such displays are not really connected via USB anyway. They only use the USB-C connector’s wires as if it was a HDMI/DisplayPort cable. It’s called an “**alternate mode**”. Where the USB chip disables itself and the connection is handed off to another chip (or SoC module).

But all this *still* does not matter, as you can just use a **USB-C-to-HDMI or -DisplayPort cable** and plug that into a HDMI or DisplayPort socket.
As you may have noticed, your PC does not come with such a connector for *incoming* connections. Only for outgoing ones.

But fear not, as you can just use a **HDMI or DisplayPort capture card or adapter**.
The cheapest I’ve seen costs only 13€.

This gives you exactly what you want.
And **notably supports showing boot output and console output, even when no X is running**.

---

Another solution would be, to just **share the display device over the network**. This was normal to Plan9, the successor to Unix that sadly never made it far out of the lab. Its protocol, **9P**, is partially supported on Linux. But I could not find any explanation on how to share the display device nodes over 9P and make it work. Especially accelerated rendering will be a problem. As will be getting BIOS/UEFI/boot messages. But in that it’s no different from *VNC*.

---

*But, given what people will also look for when finding this question, like I did, I should definitely absolutely mention **`scrcpy`** for connecting using your PC as a display for an *Android* device! Which works via adb, and essentially captures the device’s screen, and streams it as a video over adb. It even **works over wifi**, once set up via USB!

Generally, it works extremely well, and I used it to normally use a smartphone with a broken screen for well over a year. Calls, video, everything.

Just make sure, you did enable debugging over USB and authorized your PC *before* the screen breaks. ^^ … And be aware that during pin entry and such, the scrcpy display will be black. PIN entry will still work, so you merely have to enter it blind. Never was a problem though. You can even enter the pin with your PC’s keyboard through scrcpy, or use `adb shell input text $pin` if all else fails. (If you mistyped, lock the screen, unlock, and try again.)*

Of course, nothing stops you from **just streaming the display output as a video stream from one PC to another** as well. As long as your video compression is hardware accelerated by a GPU or such, it should not be slow. Certainly not if it’s perfectly fast on a simple smartphone, as scrcpy proves.

---

So yeah, as long as it’s not literally faster than light travel or such, to me there’s no such thing as, and I quote, “impossible”. ;)